# "Around {at, in} the middle of March"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I will be meeting him there on March the 16th. But I'm not really sure if I'll meet him on the 16th March, exactly. So, should I say this:

> I will be there around the middle of March.

***?***

Is the above sentence correct? Or should it be one of these:

> I will be there around **in** the middle of March.
>
> I will be there around **at** the middle of March.

***?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "around" is correct – no need for "in" or "at." (Sometimes we do use "in" and "at" together with "around," but they come first: "I'll be there at around 3:00"; "I'll arrive in around three hours.")

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement is correct.

You do not want to "stack" prepositions that each modify the same thing. You could say "I will be there *around* the middle of March" or "I will be there *in* the middle of March," but not "I will be there *around in* the middle of March." Also, you would not say "*at* the middle of March" at all.